# Did Leon Trotsky get stopped by authorities in Halifax?

Tags: communism, canada

In Antony C. Sutton's book Wall Street and the Bolshevik Revolution he argues that Leon Trotsky was given $10,000 in New York.

http://reformed-theology.org/html/books/bolshevik_revolution/chapter_02.htm

He also says Trotsky was [stopped in Halifax, Canada](http://reformed-theology.org/html/books/bolshevik_revolution/chapter_02.htm#CANADIAN%20MILITARY%20INTELLIGENCE%20VIEWS%20TROTSKY) by authorities, on his way from New York back to Europe.

Can anyone confirm that Trotsky was stopped in Halifax?

Comment: I see two different questions here, so you should break these up into separate questions with supporting information on what you want and know.  Also, ask for confirmation, argument type questions go against the FAQ.  Edit the question then ask to have it reopened.

Comment: @MichaelF is that any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two sources that say that Trotsky was detained by British naval authorities in Halifax and spent time in a detention camp in nearby Amherst.

> "British naval officials in Halifax, Nova Scotia intercepted his ship and he spent a month detained at Amherst, Nova Scotia."
>
> source: [Jewish Virtual Library](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/biography/Trotsky.html)
>
> "March 27: Trotsky and his family leave the USA by ship, but are detained by the authorities at Halifax, Nova Scotia. They are released a month later at the behest of the Russian government."
>
> source: [Glasgow University - Leon Trotsky Timeline](http://special.lib.gla.ac.uk/exhibns/trotsky/chrono.html)

So, yes Trotsky was detained by British authorities in Halifax, NS, in 1917. He and his family were on their way there from New York, NY, and it was not until the Russian government begrudgingly demanded the British release Trotsky that he was released.

Answer (score 1):

There's an engaging account of it by Silver Donald Cameron, *[Trotsky in Amherst](http://www.silverdonaldcameron.ca/trotsky-amherst)*. Imprisoned among German POWs and internees, he "turned the camp into an improvised college of socialist studies."